# Directory Monitor keep an eye on new files, modifications, deletions, renames and file access in Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

Is there any tool in Microsoft windows server 2012 keep an eye on a specific folder and get notified and changes  need to be made automatically in another folder with in same server whenever changes occurs in one folder .

These vary from new files, modifications and deletions to renames and file access. It is capable of working with network folders too .

Comment: I think with a vbscript you can do it , just add this tag ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578653/vbscript-get-copy-paste-event-from-folder?answertab=active#tab-top

Monitoring Folder with Vbscript ==> MonitorFolder.vbs You can found your LogFile for monitoring on your %AppData% folder with the name of NameofYourFolder.log.